# Ask Ubuntu logout/sign out missing

Tags: support, login

Another newbie question - where is the sign out of Ask Ubuntu? I have looked everywhere on the questions page and cannot find where to logout of Ask Ubuntu!

Answer (score 3):

Click on Stack Exchange on the upper left and then click the log out:

[image: log out link]